# foreach return выполняется 2 условия

Tags: php

Есть такой пхп код

```
$this->routes = array('index' => 'index');
$page = 'index';


foreach($this->routes as $query => $value){
        if($page == $query){
            return include ROOT."/inc/pages/$value.php";
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Если `$page` равно тому что в `$query` подключается нужный мне файл и ретурнится.

Но вот беда в чем, у меня при соблюдении условия - выполняется блок `else`.

Если условие соблюдается - срабатывает и первое и второе, если условие не выполняется - срабатывает только `else`

Почему?...

Пробовал ставить еще `break;` - не катит... :(

Comment: возможно, стоит попробовать === в условии

Comment: @jenikok какая разница. === равно добавляет лишь дополнительную проверку на тип переменной. А тип переменной string в обоих случаях

Comment: Увы, срабатывает все равно else...

Comment: У Вас не выполняется условие. Это же очевидно. У Вас переменные не равны.

Comment: Если я уберу блок "else" у меня выполняетя блок if, и если я в else укажу не return а echo к примеру, у меня выполнится и echo и return из первого

Comment: потому что include возвращает 1, вот почему

Comment: Проверил ваше мнение - все так же.
Поставил в обеих случаях return string
if($page === $query){;
                return 'Page isset';
            }else{
                return 'Page Not Found';
            }
Возвращает else и if

Comment: @user190134 он физически не может возвращать оба. Что конкретно вы получаете и сколько раз вызываете блок кода?

Comment: Проблема кроется в 
return array(
 'index' => 'index',
 'add_photo' => 'add_photo'
 );

И еще нескольких строчек добавленных...
Мне нужно если совпадение найдено - сделать выход из цикла foreach, но как?

Comment: Выход из цикла осуществляется конструкцией
    break;
Смотрите доки http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Я же написал, что break не помогает, и continue тоже, даже с указанием уровня выхода

Comment: Если break не срабатывает, значит до него не доходит выполнение скрипта. Чудес не бывает. Вообще Вам лучше бы настроить xDebug и посмотреть всё в живую.

Answer (score 3):

Выше уже написали. При успешном выполнении `include` возвращает `1`. Почитайте [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php) в абзаце "обработка возвращаемых значений". При соблюдении условия у вас не `else` отрабатывает и возвращает `1`, а `if` и возвращает `1`. Сделайте в блоке `if` не `return include`, а `return 2`, и все увидите.

Comment: Я же написал, что для теста я ипользую возвращение строки, Page Not Found(else) или Page Found(if) , и все равно возвращает мне else блок.
Я понял в чем дело, мне нужно выброс из foreach делать, но break 1; не работает

Comment: breack 1; и не будет работать. Нужно прописать следующее: $ok=include ROOT."/inc/pages/$value.php"; if ($ok==1) break;

Answer (score 0):

Вы же понимаете, что ваш цикл отработает только 1 итерацию? То есть он в принципе бессмысленный. Если у вас много элементов в `$this->routes` то в цикле не нужно писать `else`, а второй `return` писать после `foreach`:

```
function getPage($page) {
    $this->routes = array('index' => 'index');

    foreach($this->routes as $query => $value){
        if($page == $query){
            return include ROOT."/inc/pages/$value.php";
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

getPage("index");
```

А вообще если у вас массив ассоциативный, то вам цикл не нужен в принципе и работать будет на порядки быстрее:

```
$this->routes = array('index' => 'indexfile', 'test' => 'testfile');

function getPage($page) {
    if(isset($this->routes[$page])) {
        $filename = ROOT . "/inc/pages/" . $this->routes[$page] . ".php";
        if(file_exists($filename)) {
            include $filename;
            return "Page Found"
        }
    }
    return "Page Not Found";
}

getPage("index");
```